# Hunk error applying PATCH_SUPEE-10752_CE_v1.9.2.4_v1-2018 to Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, error, patches, security, supee-10752

Getting some errors applying the PATCH_SUPEE-10752_CE_v1.9.2.4_v1-2018 to my Magento 1.9.2

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
Hunk #3 succeeded at 411 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Composite/Fieldset/Options.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Datetime.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 725 with fuzz 1 (offset -10 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Wysiwyg/ImagesController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/StoreController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Tree.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Http.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 377 with fuzz 1 (offset -16 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 455 with fuzz 2 (offset -25 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 497 with fuzz 2 (offset -27 lines).
1 out of 4 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Abstract/Backend/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/Freemethod.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/OriginShipment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/Type.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/shipping/ups.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/catalog/product/links.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 353 (offset -2 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
checking file cron.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 41 with fuzz 1 (offset 1 line).
checking file js/tiny_mce/plugins/media/.htaccess
checking file lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php
```

Comment: Have you applied PATCH_SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.9.2.4_v2? if not, you'll need to revert PATCH_SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.9.2.4_v1 and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Hunk #1succeeded at 725 with fuzz 1

The message you see means the file was successfully patched, fuzz 1 means Some lines had only spaces but they got trimmed to empty lines, so the patch file applied correctly, but with fuzz factors warnings display.

---

In your case issue is only in 
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php` this file.

Please compare with core file any changes or break in varien.php file.

Hope it will helpful for you.